# How do I reach context from the same class?

Tags: c#, console-application

(Sorry for bad English i'm german)

so i got this Code which reads out certain lines:

```
    public class ZeilenLesen
    {
        public static string path1 = @"C:\temp\02\";

        public static void ReadLine()
        {
            try
            {
                var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path1, "Deploytest.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                            where line.Contains("]appName")
                            select new
                            {
                                File = file,
                                Line = line
                            };

                    foreach (var app in files)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", app.Line);
                    }
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} files found.", files.Count().ToString());
            }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx) //Die Ausnahme, die ausgelöst wird, wenn das Betriebssystem aufgrund eines E/A-Fehlers oder eines bestimmten Typs von Sicherheitsfehler den Zugriff verweigert.
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
            }
       }
```

and(Console) gives me out one Line: [string]appName = XXX

Now i want to add a if command that says:

```
if (app.Line != "[string]appName = AAA")
{
 Console.WriteLine("appname not the same");
 Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine ("appname is okay");
}
```

(Something like that)

But for some reason i cannot reach App.Line: The name app does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Where did you try to put that code?

Comment: `app` is only visible inside the foreach loop. Outside it is out of scope.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk the second code block right after the first one.

Comment: Can you check the space between "[string]appName = AAA" string or you  will try something.  if(! app.Line.contain("[string]appName = AAA"))

Comment: Be aware that `Count()` will enumerate again all the files and reopen and read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write that code outside of method.

Try this. Put the second code block inside the foreach loop

```
public class ZeilenLesen
{
    public static string path1 = @"C:\temp\02\";

    public static void ReadLine()
    {
        try
        {
            var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path1, "Deploytest.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                where line.Contains("]appName")
                select new
                {
                    File = file,
                    Line = line
                };

            foreach (var app in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", app.Line);
                if (app.Line != "[string]appName = AAA")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("appname not the same");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("appname is okay");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} files found.", files.Count().ToString());
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx) //Die Ausnahme, die ausgelöst wird, wenn das Betriebssystem aufgrund eines E/A-Fehlers oder eines bestimmten Typs von Sicherheitsfehler den Zugriff verweigert.
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much never though of that.